# не понимаю fileiutputstream.write

Tags: java

Мне нужно скопировать в один файл половину всех байтов, во второй файл вторую половину(или большую часть если количество байт не равное).

```
int size = fileInputStream.available();
        int middle;
        if(size%2==0) middle = size/2;
        else  middle = (size-1)/2 ;
        byte b[]  = new byte[size];
        while (fileInputStream.available()>0)
        {
            fileInputStream.read(b);
            fileOutputStream.write(b, 0, middle );
            fileOutputStream2.write(b, middle, b.length);
    }
 /***в этом месте вылазит эксцепшин IndexOutOfBoundsException,
             возможно я не правильно себе представляю то как работают методы,
             мне казалось что я первую половину байтов писал в первый файл,
             а вторую половину во второй файл,почему у меня не верно, и как правильно?***/
        }
```

Я неверно видимо себе преставляю write метод.
То как я себе представляю свой код внутри while (, все что выше меня особо не инетресует, просто написал чтобы меньше вопросов было о том что за переменные) Сперва пишу в массив байтов, все содержимое. потом пишу  в первый файл write от 0 до середины моего массива. Потом пишу во второй файл   с того места где оставонивил, до конца массива.? очевидно я не прав, но я не понимаю почему..., как ввод, вывести в два файла поровну(+-1байт) при помощи именно  массивов байтов?

Comment: последний элемент массива будет b.length-1

Comment: я пытался так написать, но ошибка вылетает всеравно IndexOutOfBoundsException даже если сделать -2,  ну и -1 тоже. Я непонимаю почему так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе `FileOutputStream.write()` последний параметр это количество байтов, а не индекс последнего байта, как вы предполагаете. Отсюда и исключение.

Comment: ты прояснил, спасибо.